# add bottom line to the anchor using after pseudo classes in css

Tags: html, css

trying to display  line  on the bottom of navigation anchor  with the help of before,after i try a lot to solve my problem but don't any  solution about this problem. i want to add bottom line with the help of css transform and transition using after pasudo classes

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        body,ul,li,a,nav{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    background-color: #dadada;
}

.menu-items {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-items a {
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:10px 10px;
    color: #fff;
}
.header-menu  li > a::after {
        border-color: red;
        border-style: solid;
        position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 0px;
    /*background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);*/
    content: '';
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(20px);
    transform: translateY(20px);

}
.header-menu li > a:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(1px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(1px);
    transform: translateY(1px);
}


.menu-items li {
    display: inline-block;
}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="header-menu">
            <ul class="menu-items">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Animal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Birds</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Address</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`position: relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position) to `.header-menu  li > a` or to `.menu-items a`

> **relative**
>   *This keyword lays out all elements as though the element were not positioned, and then adjust the element's position, without changing
>   layout (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have
>   been had it not been positioned). The effect of position:relative on
>   table-*-group, table-row, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption
>   elements is undefined.

then change  `top: 50%;` in `.header-menu li > a::after` to `top: 100%;`

Live DEMO

```css
body,
ul,
li,
a,
nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav {
  background-color: #dadada;
}
.menu-items {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu-items a {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative/*this will wrap pseudo elements*/
}
.header-menu li > a::after {
  border-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%; /*because we want it to be at the bottom of the anchor*/
  left: 10px; /*10px because anchor has a padding of 10px*/
  width: 50%;
  height: 0px;
  /*background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);*/
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(20px);
  transform: translateY(20px);
}
.header-menu li > a:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(1px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(1px);
  transform: translateY(1px);
}
.menu-items li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="header-menu">
  <ul class="menu-items">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Animal</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Birds</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sports</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Address</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: i get one point form your answers that is every thing in html is first positioned relative or depends on your structured

Comment: NO! position relative on a parent  gives you the control to absolutely position children elements inside of it. The default value is position: static;